# how to get all child of all childitem of all group in expandable istview (get size of all chidlren)

Tags: android, expandablelistview

coud u help get all child of all childitem of all group in expandable istview, method getchildrencout() is only get size of child in one group not for all group in expandable list.
or child.size() do too, it simple is size of childs of one group, not all group

```
enter code here

convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for (int i = 0; i < tempChild.size(); i++) {
                if(i!=childPosition)
                tempChild.get(i).setCheck(false);
                else {
                    tempChild.get(i).setCheck(true);
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: have you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

try this below code

```
for(int j=0;j<tempGroup.size();j++)
{
for (int i = 0; i < tempGroup.get(j).gettempChild.size(); i++) {
    if(i!=childPosition)
        tempGroup.get(j).gettempChild.get(i).setCheck(false);
    else {
        tempGroup.get(j).gettempChild.get(i).setCheck(true);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: oh, i have 3 variables public ArrayList<String> groupItem;
 public ArrayList<ObjectTemp> tempChild;
 public ArrayList<Object> Childtem = new ArrayList<Object>();  childitem will manage tempchild and it's contain all tempchild of all group, so your soluton?. If u need my project, u give me your name email, i'll send project

Comment: i don't see, u invi your email?, give me your email and i'll send now,

Comment: ok, i sent my project to u, or have u use yahoo chat or skype? and what's your nick?, i think it's easier to discuss in skype than on this site, do u think so